# Invalid MIME type in file sync utility

Tags: expressionengine

I get the following error in the ExpressionEngine control panel file sync utility: 
"Invalid mime type, file could not be processed"

This only happens when syncing certain file upload directories after uploading files via FTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ExpressionEngine needs to know what kind of file each file in your directories is. In order to do this it keeps a list of file/MIME types in the config/mimes.php. However some file extensions are not there (flv and mobi to name two relative common files you may upload).

If it does not see the file in that list it will throw that error.

You can add a new file MIME type to the list in mimes.php as follows:

```
'mobi' => 'application/x-mobipocket-ebook',
```

For a complete list of file extensions and their MIME types review this list:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml